# Android: real time stream to vlc from a sequence of jpgs

Tags: android, video-streaming, jpeg, vlc, rtsp

I'm working with the Sony SmartEyeGlass and I'd like to stream to VLC what the user is seeing real time. The problem is that from the handheld device I receive from the glasses a real time sequence of jpgs and not a video stream. All the guides/tutorials I'm reading utilize rtsp protocol to stream from the Android Camera. How can I stream real time to VLC from a picture sequence?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Comment: That is the library I've tried but the it uses the device camera..

Comment: I understand that you can get video from Sony. At any rate, even if the input is a set of JPEGs, you can feed them to MediaCodec same way as libstreaming does for camera frames. It's open source, exactly to make such extensions possible